# Sweet Alert custom regex validation with proper message

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) in my project. I am populating a text field inside my sweet alert input type text. I need to check it with any regex before submit and if it is successful, it should run the function otherwise it should display an error message.

```
swal({
    title: 'Edit Breakdown Variable',
    input: 'text',
    inputValue: name,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Update',
}).then(function (email) {
    if(email == ''){
        alert('err');
    }
});
```

If there is error, alert is displayed but the popup disappears after it. Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below example if it helps you.

```js
swal({
    title: 'Edit Breakdown Variable',
    input: 'text',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Update',
    preConfirm: function (email) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (email === '') {
                    alert("err");
                    reject('err')
                } else {
                    resolve()
                }
            }, 1000)
        })
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou. You saved my day. :)

Comment: after getting into `reject('err')` it will just close the popup, any reason?

Comment: popup is not closing please check the demo